# Create a descending list of orders per item and display the ranking position in seperate column

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, sql-order-by, window-functions

**[DB-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=74860becf541dceea81f77a4118aff80)**

```
CREATE TABLE operations (
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    orderID VARCHAR(255),
    itemID VARCHAR(255),
    event_date DATE,
    order_volume INT,
    shipped_volume INT
);

INSERT INTO operations
(itemID, orderID, event_date, order_volume, shipped_volume
)
VALUES 
("Item_01", "Order_XYZ", "2020-05-01", "600", "0"),
("Item_01", "Order_XYZ", "2020-05-18", "0", "315"),
("Item_01", "Order_MTE", "2020-08-15", "400", "0"),
("Item_01", "Order_MTE", "2020-08-23", "0", "120"),
("Item_01", "Order_OBD", "2020-08-21", "500", "0"),
("Item_01", "Order_OBD", "2020-11-17", "0", "380"),

("Item_02", "Order_TLP", "2020-02-02", "500", "0"),
("Item_02", "Order_TLP", "2020-02-10", "0", "175"),
("Item_02", "Order_SNE", "2020-02-03", "900", "0"),
("Item_02", "Order_SNE", "2020-03-18", "0", "620"),
("Item_02", "Order_ADF", "2020-03-27", "100", "0"),
("Item_02", "Order_ADF", "2020-03-28", "0", "30"),
("Item_02", "Order_ZGO", "2020-04-15", "375", "0"),
("Item_02", "Order_ZGO", "2020-04-17", "0", "120"),

("Item_03", "Order_BBI", "2020-03-12", "700", "0"),
("Item_03", "Order_BBI", "2020-10-25", "0", "280"),

("Item_04", "Order_DXR", "2020-12-09", "260", "0"),
("Item_04", "Order_DXR", "2020-12-15", "0", "110");
```

**Expected Result:**

```
        itemID    |   orderID   |    order_volume  |   shipped_volume  |      position
------------------|-------------|------------------|-------------------|--------------------
        Item_04   |  Order_DXR  |        260       |      110          |         1
------------------|-------------|------------------|-------------------|--------------------
        Item_03   |  Order_BBI  |        700       |      280          |         1
------------------|-------------|------------------|-------------------|--------------------
        Item_02   |  Order_ZGO  |        375       |      120          |         1
        Item_02   |  Order_ADF  |        100       |       30          |         2
        Item_02   |  Order_SNE  |        900       |      620          |         3
        Item_02   |  Order_TLP  |        500       |      175          |         4
------------------|-------------|------------------|-------------------|---------------------
        Item_01   |  Order_OBD  |        500       |      380          |         1
        Item_01   |  Order_MTE  |        400       |      120          |         2
        Item_01   |  Order_XYZ  |        600       |      315          |         3
```

---

In the results above I want to create a **descending** list of all `orderIDs` per `itemID`. 
Starting from the **newest order** to the **oldest order** which is defined by the `event_date`. 
The position of an `orderID` within a certain `itemID` should be displayed in column `position`.

---

I tried to go with this query but could not make it work:

```
SELECT
itemID,
orderID,
sum(order_volume),
sum(shipped_volume),
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY orderID ORDER BY event_date DESC) as position
FROM operations
GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY itemID DESC, orderID DESC;
```

What do I need to change to get the expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must `partition by itemid` and `order by MAX(event_date) DESC` in the `ROW_NUMBER()` window function:

```
SELECT itemID, orderID,
       sum(order_volume) order_volume,
       sum(shipped_volume) shipped_volume,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY itemID ORDER BY MAX(event_date) DESC) as position
FROM operations
GROUP BY itemID, orderID
ORDER BY itemID DESC, position;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=dfdddf5c1703dfabf38d2b7deb9c3a03).
Results:

```
> itemID  | orderID   | order_volume | shipped_volume | position
> :------ | :-------- | -----------: | -------------: | -------:
> Item_04 | Order_DXR |          260 |            110 |        1
> Item_03 | Order_BBI |          700 |            280 |        1
> Item_02 | Order_ZGO |          375 |            120 |        1
> Item_02 | Order_ADF |          100 |             30 |        2
> Item_02 | Order_SNE |          900 |            620 |        3
> Item_02 | Order_TLP |          500 |            175 |        4
> Item_01 | Order_OBD |          500 |            380 |        1
> Item_01 | Order_MTE |          400 |            120 |        2
> Item_01 | Order_XYZ |          600 |            315 |        3
```

Comment: Just for my documentation: Example 1: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=4c3098eecee37dd48fd0b92fc696f43c

Comment: Just for my documentation: Example 2: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=3d4d8157f080d09125eb239537a9705c

Answer (score 1):

You want to partition by item rather than by item (since you want to rank item orders). To sort, you need `event_date`... and an aggregate function (since there are two different dates per group): I used `MIN()`:

Consider:

```
SELECT
    itemID,
    orderID,
    SUM(order_volume) sum_ order_volume,
    SUM(shipped_volume) sum_ shipped_volume
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY itemID ORDER BY MIN(event_date) DESC) as position
FROM operations
GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY itemID DESC, position
```